# How can I find out if a particular package has been updated (or not)?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

I generally update everything that Ubuntu tells me needs updating so I don't keep a track of things that have not been updated. Recently I have been noticing differences in the behaviour of the `cpio` command. It is basically reporting errors when it did not do so a few months ago, despite none of the target files changing - that goes for their permissions also. This leads me to suspect that perhaps my `cpio` binary has been updated. My question is, is there a way that I can find this out and if so revert back to the old version. Does Ubuntu keep a log of this information anywhere? I am using version 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

There is a list of **Updates** in **History** tab in **Ubuntu Software Center**:

[image: Ubuntu Software Center]

If you are interesed by a particular package, you can search for it:

[image: Ubuntu Software Center - software]